# Why is $i^{4/3}$ not equal to 1?

Tags: arithmetic, roots-of-unity

The iteration of exponents laws I learned gives:
$$i^{4/3}=i^{4\cdot1/3}=(i^{4})^{1/3}=1^{1/3}=1$$ I know this is wrong but now the iteration of exponents laws I have used over the years somehow doesn't apply or is flawed. This is quite embarrassing as I have been studying mathematics for quite some time now. Please help.

Comment: Taking non-integer powers of complex numbers requires some care in definition and handling - generally there are multiple possible values, and in many contexts it is not possible to make a consistent choice for the whole of your domain of interest.

Comment: In $\mathbb{C}$, the familiar law of indices that you learn for positive reals are mostly lost.  $a^{bc}$ in general is not $(a^b)^c$ unless $b,c$ are nonzero integers.

Comment: $1^{1/n}=1$ is not true in general, in $\Bbb C$ you have $n$ different roots of unity. Also, working with square roots always requires some extra attentions (even in $\Bbb R$)

Comment: @Mathemagician314 this is funny

Comment: @user10354138 thank you, this is what I was looking for. So one has to use polar coordinates to calculate those kinds of expressions?

Comment: Fractional powers and roots of complex numbers is something I really, really discourage people from using, at least until they are _very_ comfortable with how complex numbers work. This is basically the reason. Using them when teaching complex numbers for the first time really does the students a grave disservice.

Comment: @MathR what do you mean?

Comment: @Mathemagician314 What you uave written is wrong, very wrong.